# When Theorems in Probability Theory require that $\mathbb{P}$(an event)$=1$, what exactly deos it mean?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I never wrapped my head around when "the probability converges to 1" is enough as opposed to being strictly "the probability is 1".

In particular, to use Doob's theorem, given a martingale $M_n$ and a stopping time $T$, $\mathbb{E}(M_T)=\mathbb{E}(M_0)$, if $\mathbb{P}(T<\infty)=1$ and $|M_n|\leq k\in \mathbb{R}, \forall n$.

But what if I can show that $\mathbb{P}(T>\infty)$ converges to 0? Does that imply $\mathbb{P}(T<\infty)=1$?

In the SSRW example, we get that $\mathbb{P}_1(V_0>V_N)=\frac{1}{N}$, but this doesn't imply that $\mathbb{P}_1(V_0<\infty)=1$, is this due to convergence is not enough to use Doob's theorem, or because "we might get lost forever in states between 0 and $N$"?

Comment: Is $\Bbb P(T\gt\infty)$ well-defined?

Comment: I do not know how to answer that. In my lectures we see that sometimes $\mathbb{P}(T < \infty)$, but not the opposite.

Comment: You can say either $\Bbb{P}(T<\infty) =1$ or equivalently, $\Bbb{P}(T=\infty) =0$. Both statements are just saying that the stopping time is finite a.e. Also, these probabilities are fixed numbers, we're not talking abiut sequences of probabilities so I'm not sure why you're even talking about probabilities converging to 1.

Comment: If $T$ is a real-valued random variable, then the set $\{T\gt\infty\}$ is empty, and of null probability. You'd have to make $T$ an extended real valued random variable for this to have any meaning

Comment: @peek-a-boo so, the probability converging to 1 is not enough then

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes the probability converging to $1$ does not hold any meaning in this context. To speak of convergence one must have a variable that goes somewhere. For instance a sequence $a_n$ can converge to a limit because $n$ may tend to infinity, and a function $f(x)$ can convergence to a limit because $x$ may tend to some $x_0$. But in the problem as you wrote it there is no variable which tends anywhere. It is a fixed expression and it does not make sense to speak of it converging.

Comment: maybe you mean $\mathbb{P}(T=\infty )$ as the expression $T>\infty $ doesn't make sense. In this case $\mathbb{P}(T=\infty )$ doesn't "converge", its just a number, a probability, there is no limiting procedure here

Comment: Perhaps you mean: $\Bbb P(T>n)$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.  This implies that $\Bbb P(T=\infty) = 0$, and in turn that $\Bbb P(T<\infty)=1$.